# Time based axis spacing JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, charts, axis, spacing

I've got some data I would like to display. This data is arranged by timestamp. Additionally this data isn't consistent, there could be 1 hour gaps between data entries, or they could be 2 minute gaps. I want to display the data on a JavaFX chart so that the spacing between points on the chart indicate the time distance entries are from each other (2 minute gap will be smaller than 1 hour gap). Is this possible in JavaFX? How can this be done?

Comment: Use numeric data for your time axis (e.g. number of minutes since some "start time"), and subclass `NumberAxis`, overriding [`getTickMarkLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#getTickMarkLabel-java.lang.Number-) to provide a string representing to appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

using **NumberAxis is appropriate** check
[http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/linechart.html]

**Example for stock** that support real-time exist in Ensemble
download Ensemble sample javafx [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html)
[image]